# Free text/XML editor where I can navigate between child parent nodes in XML?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, text-editor, notepad++

I have a huge xml file, about 300M in size. I am looking for a free editor, where when the cursor is on an element, I can quickly jump to its parent node. Visual Studio 2010 crashes when reading such a big file. Naturally the editor should be able to read such a file. I just tried an editor called PrimalXML and got an out of memory error. I couldn't find a way to do this in NotePad++. I have XML Tools plugin installed.

Comment: If this is a one-time thing, build it yourself.  If you have regular occasion to edit a 300M XML file, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: It's not wrong. There are tools which export data to xml and the file can be large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XML Marker](http://symbolclick.com).

Comment: $125 is not **Free**

Answer (score 0):

in Notepad++, use Alt-1, Alt-2, Alt-3, Alt-4 etc to navigate across levels

Comment: These collapse the xml and then I don't know how to expand them

Comment: Doesnt really help if you are on level 20...  it might help if you have nothing better, but proper XML navigation is really useful